# Prism 4.1 , Silverllight 5 and .Net 4.5.1 DelegateCommant for Button Not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, silverlight-5.0, prism-4

I'm new to Prism. I'm trying to setup a test project on Prism. I download Prism 4.1 as I found out Prism 5 doesn't work with Silverlight 5 Yet. so My configuration is Like this.

I've visual studio 2013 , Silverlight 5 and .Net 4.5.1. A basic exercise 1 Homepage divided in to 2 parts with 2 Prism module I followed for Hello world example. Done and working 1 Region Hello, 2end Regigon world

Now in Hello Module I create 1 User form. Created 1 Use.cs with INotifyPropertyChanged etc. Followed MVVM. For created Data Appeared in form. Bow I bind 1 Submit button and display change date on the same region.

I used DelegateCommand. Now working .
No Bug shown But No firing of event.

Project Structure is Like this
.Net Silverlight Navigation Application

- aprism

  - Shell.xaml
  - Bootstrapper.cs
- aprism.web

  - aprism.Hello
  - HelloView.xaml
  - HelloView.xamal.cs : UserControl , IHelloView
  - IHelloView : IView
  - IHelloViewModel : IViewModel
  - HelloViewModel : ViewModelBase, IHelloViewModel
- aprism.World
- aprism.Business

  - User.cs : INotifyPropertyChanged , IDataErrorInfo
- aprism.Infrastructure

  - IView
  - IViewModel
  - ViewMode

```cs
public interface IView
{
    IViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}

public interface IViewModel
{
    IView View { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelBase :IViewModel ,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ViewModelBase(IView view) {
        View = view;
        View.ViewModel = this;
    }
    public IView View
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}


public class HelloViewModel : ViewModelBase, IHelloViewModel
{



    public DelegateCommand SubmitRegistrationForm   { get; set; }


    public HelloViewModel(View.IHelloView view):base(view)
    {
        this.View = view;            
        this.View.ViewModel = this;
        this.HelloText = "Prism Hello..";
        CreateUse();
        //User.PropertyChanged +=User_PropertyChanged;
        this.SubmitRegistrationForm = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);

    }



   /* private void User_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitRegistrationForm.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }*/

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Save()
    {
       User.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    }



    #region IHelloViewModel Members

    public string HelloText { get; set; }

    private User _user;
    public User User {
        get { return _user; }
        set 
        {
            _user = value;               
            OnPropertyChanged("User");
        }
    }

    private void CreateUse() {
        User = new User()
        {
            Username="Anand",
            Email = "akirti.iitk@gmail.com",
            Password = "delasoft",
            ConfirmPassword = "delasoft"
        };
    }

   /* public Infrastructure.IView View
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    */
    #endregion

}
```

```xml
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"   
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"    x:Class="Hpmsprism.Hello.View.HelloView"   
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hpmsprism.Business;assembly=Hpmsprism.Business" 
    xmlns:Commands="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism"
    d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:User x:Key="cUser"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HelloText}" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,35,0,0" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="User Registration" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>        
        <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Height="28" Margin="110,96,0,0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Content=" User Name : "/>
        <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="28" Margin="110,129,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Content=" Email : "/>
        <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="28" Margin="110,157,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Content=" Password : "/>
        <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="28" Margin="110,204,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Content=" Confirm Password : "/>

        <Button Content="Register" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="342,301,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" x:Name="SubmitRegisterForm" Commands:Click.Command="{Binding Path=SubmitRegistrationFormCommand}"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="247,92,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding User.Username,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" x:Name="UserName"
                 />

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="247,125,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding User.Email,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" x:Name="Email"/>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,157,0,0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" x:Name="Password"
                     Password="{Binding User.Password,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,200,0,0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" x:Name="ConfirmPassword"
                     Password="{Binding User.ConfirmPassword,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <sdk:Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="110,257,0,0" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Content=" Date Updated :"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,257,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="{Binding User.DateUpdated}" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="DateUpdated"/>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Button Doesn't fire Submit Command.
PLease Help me.
Thank you

Comment: i checked on Firebug I see 1 Continuous URL Running  curl 'http://localhost:53585/95d62e54f082421092dc0a8a79e36056/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAATdWrXkaJm063YpNlm5suLQAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACGKB%2B7i6GvIb5lplROtmFjWHOjXnF1hMnC7FqAXZZ90wAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADOWGroUX9iVp18Q5PWUN1PiN%2F1HzCvJ4IhdPPX7u9mzjAAAAAW33WjC%2BMEg5%2BWNU2304xXlSH%2BxDMZSfz7iFZg

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got It working. After Polishing my MVVM Concept & Unity Again.

**Problem is Any Property used in HelloViewModel should have the signature in IHelloViewModel Interface too. And for this Property I Need to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged too.**

So I did Like this :

```
private DelegateCommand _command;
    public DelegateCommand SubmitRegistrationFormCommand
    {
        get { return _command; }
        set { _command = value; OnPropertyChanged("SubmitRegistrationFormCommand"); }
    }
// This in Implementation
```

and In Interface I had a Property Signature to Like this

```
DelegateCommand SubmitRegistrationFormCommand{set;get;}
```

This may be When Ioc Loads & Map this interface is the role play Thing as DataContext is of Type this ViewModel after Setting the Property

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/531eb18f-3060-4adf-a44e-8dffe0fcbd07/prism-41-silverlight-5-with-net-451-delegatecommand-not-working?forum=wpf

Initially Didn't work for me until I didn't mapped my Interface.

Comment: Now I've 1 Issue that is Why Browser is Firing continues GEt Request. Please help. Reponse back is like this

{"C":"d-53AC0465-1,0|BA,5|BB,0","M":["{\"name\":\"sys.callback\",\"args\":[2,\"http://localhost:49384/__browserLink/requestData/d25dc8b645c641d5a89ed1172853b00f\"],\"callbackId\":-1}","{\"name\":\"sys.callback\",\"args\":[3,[\"D:\\\\development\\\\prism41\\\\myproject\\\\hpmsp.Web\\\\hpmspTestPage.aspx\"]],\"callbackId\":-1}","{\"name\":\"sys.callback\",\"args\":[4,[]],\"callbackId\":-1}"]}